Compare many files to one file
Can WinMerge be used to compare contents of multiple files to the contents of one, authoritative/original file?  For example, I want to compare all files with the same name within a folder structure to a baseline file to see which ones are direct copies and which ones have been modified and how much.  I have tried...
1st File or Folder
C:\folder\file.xml
2nd File or Folder
C:\otherFolder\*\file.xml
...but I see

Right (2nd) path is invalid!

Or is this something I'll need to write my own program to do?
